# Boolean expression simplification.

Tags: logic

Can anyone please simplify this boolean expression ? My answer always reduces to a single variable i.e $x$ but my instructor reduced to three literals.
 $$x'y'z+x'yz'+xy'z'+xyz$$

Comment: There's no simplification here, since it's an OR of $4$ out of $8$ possible options, so all you could do is OR on the NOT of the other $4$ options, i.e., $(x'yz)'+(xy'z)'+(xyz')'+(x'y'z')'$.

Comment: This expression is the exclusive or of $x$, $y$, $z$.  On a K-map, it has a characteristic checkerboard pattern, which immediately tells you it can't be simplified.  Algebraically, the consensus theorem doesn't apply; since no term is properly contained in another, the expression is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\begin{split}
x'y'z+x'yz'+xy'z'+xyz
 &= x'(y'z+yz') + x(y'z' + yz) \\
 &= x'(\overline{yz'} + yz') + x(\overline{yz} + yz)
\end{split}
$$
and now note that if $y=0=z$ then the expression comes out $x$ and in all other cases, it will depend of $x'$ - you cannot really simplify any further

Answer (score 1):

$$x'y'z+x'yz'+xy'z'+xyz = x \text{ xor } y \text{ xor } z$$

There's an even number of negations in each term.

Answer (score 0):

You have $3$ variables, hence $2^3=8$ possible combinations of them.

Your expression is an OR on $4$ out of these $8$ combinations:

$x'y'z+x'yz'+xy'z'+xyz$.

So there isn't really any way to simplify it.

You can do an OR on the NOT of the other $4$ combinations:

$(x'yz)'+(xy'z)'+(xyz')'+(x'y'z')'$.

But that leaves you with an expression of the same "size"...